# Getting syntax error while running a SQL script in psql

Tags: postgresql

I get a syntax error when running the below command.

```
yyyyyydb=# psql yyyyyydb< /tmp/yyyyyydb_bkp_11202017.sql;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
LINE 1: psql waivrdb < /tmp/yyyyyydb_bkp_11202017.sql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`psql` is a command line program, not a SQL command. Your prompt shows that you are already inside of `psql` so you don't need to start that program again.

To run a SQL script from within psql, use the `\i` command:

```
waivrdb=# \i /tmp/waivrdb_bkp_11202017.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running a shell command `psql waivrdb < /tmp/waivrdb_bkp_11202017.sql` inside the postgres client rather than from your shell. So, run `psql waivrdb < /tmp/waivrdb_bkp_11202017.sql` from the shell and you should be good.

You can also run `\i /tmp/waivrdb_bkp_11202017.sql` from inside the postgres client.